# Updating a SQL Alchemy list without reloading the page?

Tags: ajax, flask

I am working on a small Flask app and the user is able to update a list of items via using a form to submit some data.

I am currently using SQL Alchemy as the ORM for my database and using the list in my template to display the items. I want to update it so that when the list is updated. The page is updated without the user having to reload the page.

I have tried this with AJAX using the below script but the update is not occurring.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('form').on('submit',function (e) {
         $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: '/todo',
          data: $('#todoInput').serialize(),
           success: function (q) {
           console.log(q);
           }
          });
         e.preventDefault();
         });

    }
```

My template:

```
{%  extends "base.html" %}

{% block script %}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/custom.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
{% if messages %}
{% for message in messages %}
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
    {{ message }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endwith %}
<div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col-md-auto">
        <h1>What needs to be done today?</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col-md-auto">
        <form action="" method="post">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.todo (id="todoInput") }}
                {{ form.submit (class_="btn btn-primary btn-sm") }}
            </div>
        </form>
            <div id="todoList">
                <ul class="list-group">
                {% for todo in todos %}
                    <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    {{ todo.body }}
                    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Model:

```
from datetime import datetime
from app import db, login
from flask_login import UserMixin
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash


class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    todos = db.relationship('Todo', backref='owner', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.username)

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)


@login.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(int(id))


class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.String(140))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Todo {}>'.format(self.body)
```

Route:

```
@app.route('/todo', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def todo():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        form = TodoForm()
        todos = current_user.todos.order_by(Todo.timestamp.desc()).all()
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            new_todo = Todo(body=form.todo.data, owner=current_user)
            db.session.add(new_todo)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Todo added')
            todos = current_user.todos.order_by(Todo.timestamp.desc()).all()
            return render_template('todo.html', form=form, todos=todos)
        return render_template('todo.html', form=form, todos=todos)
    flash('You first need to login or register')
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

The `todos` list is what im trying to update. But it just reloads the page :/

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things. Firstly you need to be sure that your database is updated. That means that your form was submitted successfully. This can be done by submitting the form manually via an ajax call. This is more or less what you did. Did you check, whether your backend receives the form-submission and updates the database?

Secondly you need to update the html in the browser. Normally the page is refreshed automatically if your form is submitted. If you dont want a page reload, you need to add some client-side logic, to ensure that the page is updated. This can easily be done with a little bit of javascript.

Edit:
Your custom js might be missing `});` at the end. Or did you just forget to post it here?